# How to pass a variable in a URL

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-router

I want to pass the `projectId` along with the `url`. How can I achieve that?

```
    var projectId = e.data.id;
    var url = `/pages/project_details/,`projectId`,/Ongoing`;
    this.router.navigateByUrl(url).then(e =>{
      if(e){
        console.log('routed');
      }else{
        console.log('not routed');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You are using Angular 7 or up version than you can use following standard of typescript

```
const projectId = e.data.id;;
const url = '/pages/project_details/' + projectId + '/Ongoing'; 
console.log(url )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this.

```
var projectId = e.data.id;
var url = `/pages/project_details/${projectId}/Ongoing`;
console.log(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var projectId = 12345; // example project id
var url = '/pages/project_details/'+projectId+'/Ongoing';

print(url)
// output: /pages/project_details/12345/Ongoing
```